# Why doesn't returning false from OnClientClick cancel the postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, onclientclick

I have a `LinkButton` where I use the `OnClientClick` property to ask the user whether he really wants to perform an action, e.g:

```
<script>
function confirmDelete() {
  return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');
}
</script>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete()" ... />
```

This pattern usually works, but on this specific page, it doesn't. No matter whether I click OK or Cancel in the confirm dialog, the postback is executed.

---

Just for completeness (to answer pst's question): the rendered HTML is OK. E.g. it looks like this:

```
<a id="ctl00_c1_content_btnDelete" onclick="return confirmDelete();"
 href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(..))"
... >
  Delete
</a>
```

Comment: The resulting HTML generated is...?

Comment: @pst: the HTML is OK. See my answer below - I just posted this for others which might have the same problem.

Comment: @pst: can't yet - have to wait until tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the behavior was another piece of javascript, where a handler for the link(button)'s click event was registered via jquery, e.g. something similar to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    // ...
    return (someCondition == true);
  });
});
</script>
```

It seems this click-handler was called after the one registered by `OnClientClick`, and when this one returned `true`, then the postback occurred, independent of the result of the first click-handler (the confirm dialog).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something which worked for me.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return (!confirmDelete()){return false;}" />
```

**Javascript**

```
    function confirmDelete(){
    if(something == true){
    return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: That value in OnClientClick gave me an error, but this worked: OnClientClick="if(!confirmDelete()){return false;}"