# A simple "back" button in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, back

This should be so simple, and indeed I have found many solutions on SO and elsewhere. But nothing I do seems to work. This is what I currently have:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BackButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/redAbort.png"
    OnClientClick="backClick()" CssClass="TVMback-button" />
```

And:

```
function backClick(sender) {                                    
    history.back(1);
    return false;
}
```

But the page just refreshes. I get to this page using Javascript (via document.location), by the way. And I really do want to implement a "back" function here, rather than targeting a preset URL, as I could end up here from various sources. But even when I do try to set document.location to the URL of the previous page, nothing happens.

So I guess I've missed something stupid simple.

I have tried a bazillion of combinations though. Including prefacing history with `document.` and `window.`, as well as trying `.go(-1)`, etc.

I have also tried returning `false`, `true`, nothing at all. I have tried to return Santa Claus and the shoes I bought for my girlfriend in Raleigh, NC back in 2012, as they were a size too big. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Browsers come with a nice big back button. Just let users use that. There's no point in trying to duplicate its functionality.

Comment: What Quentin said, plus [(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893963/asp-net-onclientclick-return-false-doesnt-work)

Comment: Quentin: Maybe I should have been clearer on that: This application is designed to run on an embedded system with touch screen input only. No toolbar etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not propagating the value returned by `backClick()` from the event handler.

You should write:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BackButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/redAbort.png"
    OnClientClick="return backClick();" CssClass="TVMback-button" />
```

Also note that `history.back()` does not take an argument, so you only have to write:

```
function backClick()
{
    history.back();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ooooooh! I feel like such a dimwit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use html. No need for the ASP.

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```